# Keyboard shortcuts stringification standards?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, standards

I noticed there must be some "best practices" or standards when it comes to describing keyboard shortcuts in text such as in Visual Studio Code.

Where can one find the "standards" for ordering key combinations in keyboard shortcuts?

For instance what is correct order of modifiers?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings